# Hardware Security Module: How to use Digital Signatures

Tags: c#, security, hsm

I have a request from the client. They wish to use SafeNet HSM replacement for USB digital signature. I get a lot of SDKs for Win64 file as: fm_sdk, hsm_net_server, network_hsm_access_provider, ptkc_sdk, . I have tried to find out on Google on how to look like?

Please guide me **how to create digital signature function PDF** from Hardware Security Modules using C#.

Comment: You need to read safenet HSM documentation

Comment: I agree with you. But I was read a lot of document. And hmmmmmm  i think i want sample @@

Comment: well mate https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=HSM

Answer (score 0):

Your C# application can use Microsoft CAPI or CNG API provided by safenet SDK. As a 2nd option you can also use [ncryptoki](http://www.ncryptoki.com/) which is PKCS #11 compliant.